# Rails custom routes with scopes

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a scope 'games-posts' in my Post model that fetches posts that belong to a Topic with a title "Games" (Post belongs_to Topic). In my routes I have defined the route `get 'games-posts', to: 'topics#games'` and have the view where I show the list of those games posts. In each of the posts I have a link that takes me to that specific games post. 
Apart from that I have regular `resources :posts` routes that the generate standard urls:

```
`/posts`
`/posts/:id`
`/posts/:id/edit`
```

etc.

My problem is that when I click on a specific post on `games-posts` page right now it redirects me to `/posts/1` (for example). 
It would be cool if it redirected me to `/games-posts/1` instead of `/posts/1` and similarily I would like to edit and destroy those posts from `games-posts` page. How can I accomplish this? Is it possible to define something like

`resources :games-posts`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `:controller` option lets you explicitly specify a controller to use for the resource. For example:

```
resources :games_posts, controller: 'posts'
```

Now run `rake routes` and you will get following output to verify if it generated your required paths.

```
    games_posts GET    /games_posts(.:format)                                   posts#index
                POST   /games_posts(.:format)                                   posts#create
 new_games_post GET    /games_posts/new(.:format)                               posts#new
edit_games_post GET    /games_posts/:id/edit(.:format)                          posts#edit
     games_post GET    /games_posts/:id(.:format)                               posts#show
                PATCH  /games_posts/:id(.:format)                               posts#update
                PUT    /games_posts/:id(.:format)                               posts#update
                DELETE /games_posts/:id(.:format)                               posts#destroy
```

Comment: Wonderful! Also `scope do
     resources :posts, path: 'games-posts'
   end` does what I need :) Thank you so much!